# How to export/import db?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a remote server running a huge Oracle 11g database on a Docker that I need to export/import on my local machine.

I have already tried 2 approaches:

- an attempt to copy db through SQLDeveloper led to `Time Out` exception
- `save` running container into an image and `load` it after also
  didn't help as an initialization error occurred. The size of resulting `image.tar` made up 10.5GB.

By reason of Oracle is commonly used in production environment and designed to cope with big amounts of data I'm sure there must be clear off-the-shelf solution to export/import a db from one host to another.

Could you give me any ideas, please?

Comment: Use Datapump: `expdp` and `impdp`

Comment: Is it not deprecated? Could you tell me what exact commands should I use?

Comment: `exp` and `imp` are deprecated, but not datapump `expdp` and `impdp`